# How many bytes in a map in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, memory, dictionary

I have a [map](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/containers.mapclass.html) called `res_Map`, containing a set of arrays of varying size. I want to find the total memory used to store `res_Map`.

As you can see below, it looks as if `res_Map` takes up almost no memory at all, whereas the individual elements in `res_Map` do.

```
res_1 = res_Map(1);
>> whos
  Name              Size             Bytes  Class             Attributes

  res_1           118x100            94400  double                      
  res_Map          11x1                112  containers.Map
```

Does anyone know how I can find the actual memory used to store `res_Map`? I can't find any info about this in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/containers.mapclass.html).

Comment: I think that this related question might help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388409/how-can-i-tell-how-much-memory-a-handle-object-uses-in-matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388409/how-can-i-tell-how-much-memory-a-handle-object-uses-in-matlab).

Comment: Thanks @horchler! It worked perfectly. Assuming that the comments to  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2389080/2338750 is correct, saying that the conversion to struct does not take up much memory, this seems like a simple way of doing it. I think it's very strange that these sorts of tricks are necessary in Matlab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `containers.Map` object is a Matlab object like any other.  Under the hood these are implemented as a Matlab structures with some additional access controls and function mappings.

You can force Matlab to show you the raw structure using the `struct` command.  This throws a warning, as it is usually not recommended.  However, the structure view of the class shows the complete contents, and is accurately reflected in a `whos` call.

Some example code is below:

```
%Initialize map and add some content
res_Map = containers.Map;
for ix = 1:1000
    res_Map(sprintf('%05d',ix)) = ix;
end

%Look at the memory used by the map
disp('Raw who:  always 112 Bytes for Map')
whos('res_Map')

%Force the map into a structure, and look at the contained memory
mapContents = struct(res_Map);
disp('Look at the size of the map contents, reflect true size')
whos('res_Map','mapContents')


%Add additional contents and check again.
for ix = 1001:2000
    res_Map(sprintf('%05d',ix)) = ix;
end
mapContents = struct(res_Map);
disp('Look at the size of the map contents, reflect true size')
whos('res_Map','mapContents')
```

The result of the above script (after removing the warning messages) is shown below:

```
Raw who:  always 112 Bytes for Map
Name            Size            Bytes  Class             Attributes
res_Map      1000x1               112  containers.Map

Look at the size of the map contents, reflect true size
Name                Size             Bytes  Class             Attributes
mapContents         1x1             243621  struct
res_Map          1000x1                112  containers.Map


Look at the size of the map contents, reflect true size
Name                Size             Bytes  Class             Attributes    
mapContents         1x1             485621  struct
res_Map          2000x1                112  containers.Map
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a script to do this for any `struct` over at [matlab central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12278), which I believe will also work for a map.

To implement it yourself, you need to recurse over the content of the map and subsequently over all the fields in the `struct`s or `cell`s it may contain to determine the sizes.

Comment: Nice. An alternative to `whos` (or an overloaded version) that returned true memory usage for all variable would be nice too.

Comment: Yes, it would be. Pretty surprising it does not exist currently (to my knowledge).