# Freeing up memory from Matlab's Map

Tags: matlab, dictionary, memory-management

I've got a problem which requires me to keep track of a large amount of data in a hard to predict way. I do know a few rules however that allow me to determine when some data is not needed anymore.

I was thinking of using a `containers.Map` to store the data as it is produced in an efficient way (as I cannot specify a large enough empty matrix to hold all my data).
I would then run my code and at each step, if the conditions are met, clear some of the stored data using `remove(M, keys)`.

However I've run a very basic test and the memory allocated to the Map doesn't seem to change when I remove elements. Here is the test I ran:

```
testmap = containers.Map([1,2,3],[11,22,33])
whos testmap % outputs a size of 3x1 as expected and an allocation of 8 Bytes
remove(testmap,[1]);
whos testmap % outputs a size of 2x1 as expected ... but still an allocation of 8 Bytes
```

Am I looking at the right thing here? Is there another way to proceed to have a data container which can be dynamically adjusted in terms of memory usage?

Thanks.

Comment: I've read somewhere that containers.Map is a wrapper around Java's java.util.HashMap.  It does look like HashMap [never shrinks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2811633/6579744). More efficient alternatives may be suggested if you give further details in a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that even an *empty* map is 8 bytes, so your test isn't telling you anything

```
testmap = containers.Map();
whos testmap

% Name         Size            Bytes  Class             Attributes
% testmap      0x1                 8  containers.Map
```

The container itself takes up very little memory, we have to take a lead from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902910/how-many-bytes-in-a-map-in-matlab) to determine the size of the associated map data

```
testmap = containers.Map(1:10,1:10);
testmap_s = struct(testmap);
whos testmap_s

% Name           Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes
% testmap_s      1x1              3809  struct    

remove(testmap,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8});
testmap_s = struct(testmap);
whos testmap_s

% Name           Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes
% testmap_s      1x1              2017  struct
```

So yes, this should work for your application, the data will be cleared from the map, and pending any additional memory management by MATLAB should be "forgotten" in due course.